# GitLab CI - if variable exists set variable

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'd like to set a dash plus the repo tag to a Docker image build if the build is a build of a tag, and neither if it is not, I'll explain...

This would be trivial if I just wanted to set the tag if it existed because this would work:

```
build-nginx:
  stage: build-nginx
  script:
    - command docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:nginx$CI_COMMIT_TAG .
    - command docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:nginx$CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

This could create `registry.example.com/image:nginx` if there was no tag and `registry.example.com/image:nginx1.0` if there was, but how would I get the image to be named `registry.example.com/image:nginx-1.0` (with a dash), I've have to check if the tag variable was set otherwise I'd end up with and image called `registry.example.com/image:nginx-` if the tag variable was not set.

Comment: I have solved this for now by splitting and duplicating my stages and using "only: - tags".

Answer (score 6):

Normally I do something like

```
- if [ -z "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" ]; then docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:nginx$CI_COMMIT_TAG .; else docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:nginx-$CI_COMMIT_TAG; fi
```